# Place image at random position but not out of screen

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im trying to place an image inside a canvas, but not out of the screen.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width - 74) < 0 ? 1 : value;
```

The value `74` is the image width, I thought I'd do that so I wont go too far rigth on the  `X`. But when the random value is about 20 is will go a bit outside on the left.

Hope this is clear and someone can help me.

**EDIT:**

Basically this:

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width - 74);
x = x <= 0 ? 1 : x;
```

But in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `Math.random() * (canvas.width - 74)` creates a value between `0` and `canvas.width - 74`

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - 74));
```